# Load unregistered COM object

Tags: python, win32com

How can I load an unregistered COM object?

I have a dll called ResultScript.dll. If registered, then I can easily load it with the below lines:

```
import win32com.client
bin_reader = win32com.client.Dispatch('ResultScript.BinReader')
```

However, the dll is unregistered and I get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    bin_reader = win32com.client.Dispatch('ResultScript.BinReader')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)
```

Due to admin restrictions, I cannot register the dll and I am looking for workarounds.
I have seen a similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112495/accessing-unregistered-com-objects-from-python-via-a-registered-tlb) but I can't understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Import `getobject.py` and try calling the function [here](https://gist.github.com/EBNull/4219140#file-getobject-py-L133):

```
getobject.CoCreateInstanceFromDll(r"c:\path\to.dll", clsid_of_ResultScript_BinReader)
```

Since you're operating on the class directly, you'll need the class ID (clsid) instead of the friendly name (ResultScript.BinReader).